# onClick not working with Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, button, input, onclick, alert

I want to get an alert after the button `loadTweets` has been clicked. Can anyone tell me why I am not getting an alert? I am getting a "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: test" as a result. I've tried both the shown method as well as the `(#loadTweets).click(test())` method.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="data_generator.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="button" id="loadTweets" onClick="test()" value="load tweets">
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
  function test() {
    alert("HELLO WORLD!")
  }
  ...
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the code it is because the function is not in global scope. It is in scope of the closure in the ready call. `(#loadTweets).click(test())` does not work because you are calling the method, not referencing it.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Is your `...` supposed to contain a missing `})`?

Comment: Are you getting any error, see the console, might be your jquery path is not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "loadTweets" ).on( "click", test);
```